# Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given

Tags: flutter, dart, compiler-errors

For some reason there is this error(Title) it shows when I try to use ChatsScreen. For Example in the following code the brackets of ChatsScreen are red underlined.

```
int _selectedItem = 0;
 final List<Widget> _page = [
   Center(child: Text("Home Screen"),),
   ChatsScreen(),
   ProfileScreen(),
 ];
```

This is the code of the ChatsScreen (There is no error shown in this code):

```
class ChatsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String routeName = "ChatsScreen";

  UserModel user;
  ChatsScreen(this.user);

  @override
  State<ChatsScreen> createState() => _ChatsScreenState();
}


class _ChatsScreenState extends State<ChatsScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Chats"
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange.shade500,
      ),

      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(widget.user.uid).collection("messages").snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.hasData){
            if(snapshot.data.docs.length < 1) {
              return Center(
                child: Text(
                  "No Chats Available"
                ),
              );
            }
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  var friendId = snapshot.data.docs[index].id;
                  var lastMsg = snapshot.data.docs[index]["last_msg"];
                  return FutureBuilder(
                      future: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(friendId).get(),
                      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot asyncSnapshot) {
                        if(asyncSnapshot.hasData) {
                          var friend = asyncSnapshot.data;
                          return ListTile(
                            leading: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80),
                              child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                imageUrl: friend["image"],
                                placeholder: (context, url)=>CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                errorWidget: (context, url, error)=>Icon(Icons.error),
                                height: 50,
                              ),
                            ),
                                title: Text(friend["name"]),
                                subtitle: Container(
                                  child: Text(
                                    "$lastMsg",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.grey,
                                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>ChatScreen(
                                  currentUser: widget.user,
                                  friendId: friend["uid"],
                                  friendName: friend["name"],
                                  friendImage: friend["image"],
                              ),
                              ),
                              );
                            }
                          );
                        }
                        return LinearProgressIndicator();
                      },
                  );
                }
            );
          }
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.search),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> SearchScreen(widget.user)));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I feel like there's something meant to be in the brackets behind ChatsScreen but idk.
I hope somebody understands my problem because I for sure don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give user as parameter like this `ChatScreen(user);`.

It should look like this, the error will go away

```
int _selectedItem = 0;
 final List<Widget> _page = [
   Center(child: Text("Home Screen"),),
   ChatsScreen(user),
   ProfileScreen(),
 ];
```

Also change this part of `ChatScreen` like this,

```
class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChatScreen(this.user, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static String routeName = "ChatsScreen";
  final UserModel user;
  @override
  State<ChatScreen> createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}
```

Comment: Hey man, first of I'm really thankful that you answered and I've tried it out but the problem then is that "user" is red underlined and I'm given the options to "Create getter user" or to "Create field user" but both don't really work out. So I was wondering if u know what to do now?

Comment: Edited. Change the top part of ChatScreen like in the answer.

Comment: I changed it and now the Error changed to: "Undefined name 'user'."

Comment: Instead of typing "user" you have to give an object of type UserModel.

Comment: How exactly do I do that? Btw I appreciat that you're trying to help.

Comment: ChatScreen(UserModel())

Comment: It FINALLY works can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of your `ChatScreen` class, expects a parameter:

```
ChatsScreen(this.user);
```

So when creating an instance, you should pass in a parameter of `UserModel` type.

If that's not intended, you should change the constructor to allow the parameter being optional.